# Wordpress Elementor FOUC php looping

Tags: php, wordpress

I wanted to know how can I pull list of data from array and loop the array 1 by 1 inside a template.

I tried this, :

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
      if ( ! class_exists(
  '\Elementor\Core\Files\CSS\Post' ) ) {
            return;
      }

$template_id = array('5134','5131','5128','5125');
foreach ($template_id as $x) {
      $css_file = new \Elementor\Core\Files\CSS\Post( $x );
      $css_file->enqueue();
}, 1500 );
```

as you can see I wanted to pull the template_id array = such as 5134 into $css_file = new \Elementor\Core\Files\CSS\Post( $x ); . But i cannot seem to make it to work.

I was expecting if I can loop $css_file = new \Elementor\Core\Files\CSS\Post( $x ); 1 by 1 by using the template_id data.